# Decoding AAC to PCM with ffmpeg results in noise

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, decoding, pcm, aac

I have a .mp4 file generated with ffmpeg as follows.

> ffmpeg -y -i video_extended.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:04.00 -i output5-1.wav -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ac 6 -ar 48000 -b:a 128k -async 1 mixed.mp4

Playing `mixed.mp4` file with ffplay is fine and there is no impact to the sound quality. Below is the output I get from ffplay when using the command `ffplay -i  mixed.mp4`

```
> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
> 'mixed_h264_aac_512k_async_qp0_all_I.mp4':   Metadata:
>     major_brand     : isom
>     minor_version   : 512
>     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
>     encoder         : Lavf58.76.100   Duration: 00:00:16.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 49136 kb/s   Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p10le(progressive),
> 1920x1080, 65409 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 11988 tbn (default)
>     Metadata:
>       handler_name    : VideoHandler
>       vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]   Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 71 kb/s (default)
>     Metadata:
>       handler_name    : SoundHandler
>       vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0] Switch subtitle stream from #-1 to #-1 vq= 1606KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Then, I decode the `mixed.mp4` file back to raw PCM using the following command.

> ffmpeg -i mixed.mp4 -vn -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 6 raw_audio.pcm

However, this `raw_audio.pcm` contains a lot of noise and ffplay output shows the following output

```
[s16le @ 0x7f7490000c80] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, s16le, from 'separated_audio_s16.pcm':
  Duration: 00:00:16.02, bitrate: 4607 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 6 channels, s16, 4608 kb/s
[pcm_s16le @ 0x7f749002b940] Multiple frames in a packet.
[pcm_s16le @ 0x7f749002b940] Invalid PCM packet, data has size 8 but at least a size of 12 was expected
    Last message repeated 32 times
[pcm_s16le @ 0x7f749002b940] Invalid PCM packet, data has size 8 but at least a size of 12 was expected
    Last message repeated 11 times
Switch subtitle stream from #-1 to #-1 vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[pcm_s16le @ 0x7f749002b940] Invalid PCM packet, data has size 8 but at least a size of 12 was expected
    Last message repeated 11 times
[pcm_s16le @ 0x7f749002b940] Invalid PCM packet, data has size 8 but at least a size of 12 was expected
    Last message repeated 11 times
[pcm_s16le @ 0x7f749002b940] Invalid PCM packet, data has size 8 but at least a size of 12 was expected
```

Can someone please explain the issue here? Note that the ffplay command that works correctly for `mixed.mp4` shows  `fltp` as the audio format, whereas when playing the `raw_audio.pcm` file, it is seen as s16.

Is this a resampling issue in ffmpeg, and how can I rectify this?

I’m using ffmpeg and ffplay versions 5.0.1 in a Fedora 36 system.

Thank you.

Comment: would it play ok if you save as`.wav` file? `s16 sample_fmt` is what you asked for by using `pcm_s16le` codec. If you want to retain the format, use `pcm_f32le` instead.

Comment: The issue remains the same. ffmpeg -i ChID-BLITS-EBU-Narration.mp4 -vn -acodec pcm_f32le -f f32le -ar 48000 -ac 6 audio_f32.pcm. Playing back this is also distorted. My goal is basically to get a S16 raw audio stream.

Comment: if it uses `pcm_s16le` as codec try use a `-dither_method ‘modified_e_weighted’`. The noise happens when audio is downsampled

Comment: @tony: did you mean something like this, ffmpeg -i ChID-BLITS-EBU.mp4 -vn -acodec pcm_s16le -dither_method modified_e_weighted -ar 44100 -ac 6 -f s16le ChID-BLITS-EBU-raw.wav. It presents the same issue. Also, same happens for f32le as well. Stereo channels work fine. The issue seems to be with 5.1 or higher.

Comment: Update: I have inspected the decoded stream from above commands in Audacity and found out that it plays fine, and is identical to the original input. This looks like an issue in ffplay.